WARN and FORBIDWARN
I have a question about the Welsh hunspell dict pack.
https://github.com/fin-w/LibreOffice-Geiriadur-Cymraeg-Welsh-Dictionary/blob/main/dictionaries/cy_GB.aff
I can see that these 2 lines are used in the affix file.
WARN !
FORBIDWARN

And used in the corpus like this...
adlamu/H
adlamych/H!

But it is also possible to use this option...
FORBIDDENWORD !

Is it any different than the WARN parameter?

Both commands as same as confirmed by the author of that affix file here...
https://github.com/fin-w/LibreOffice-Geiriadur-Cymraeg-Welsh-Dictionary/issues/2#issuecomment-2116546330
